# How can I Join two dataframe and keep all key column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to inner join 2 dataframes using the same key I created several temporary dataframe while doing the join The code below works fine, but I wonder if there is a way to keep both of the join key columns when joining the two pandas dataframes below with subj as key.

```
head = [['nationality', 'BART', 'USA']]
body = [['placeOfBirth', 'BART', 'NEWYORK'], ['hasFather', 'BART', 'HOMMER']]
head_df = pd.DataFrame(head, columns = ['pred', 'subj', 'obj'])
body_df = pd.DataFrame(body, columns = ['pred', 'subj', 'obj'])
joined_df = pd.merge(head_df, body1_df, how='inner' ,on='subj')
```

I have these two dataframe

head_df :

```
          pred  subj  obj
0  nationality  BART  USA
```

body_df :

```
           pred  subj      obj
0  placeOfBirth  BART  NEWYORK
1     hasFather  BART   HOMMER
```

I want to join(inner) these 2 dataframes based on subj (head_df) and subj (body_df).

My desired output is

```
        pred_x subj_x obj_x        pred_y subj_y    obj_y
0  nationality   BART   USA  placeOfBirth   BART  NEWYORK
1  nationality   BART   USA     hasFather   BART   HOMMER
```

Thanks

Comment: What's the usage of such duplicated columns if they are sure to be of same contents ?   You can just create a duplicate column and rename the old / new columns anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add "_x" and "_y" to column labels, use `suffixes`.

`joined_df = pd.merge(head_df, body_df, how='inner', on='subj', suffixes=['_x', '_y'])`

The result will be:

```
    pred_x  subj    obj_x   pred_y  obj_y
0   nationality BART    USA placeOfBirth    NEWYORK
1   nationality BART    USA hasFather   HOMMER
```

I don't know why you need duplicated joining columns. How about just copying those columns?

```
joined_df = pd.merge(head_df, body_df, how='inner', on='subj', suffixes=['_x', '_y'])
joined_df.rename(columns={'subj':'subj_x'}, inplace=True)
joined_df['subj_y'] = joined_df['subj_x']
```

The result will be:

```
    pred_x  subj_x  obj_x   pred_y  obj_y   subj_y
0   nationality BART    USA placeOfBirth    NEWYORK BART
1   nationality BART    USA hasFather   HOMMER  BART
```